# Why does `as.numeric(c(1, 1.0, "1.0", TRUE))` return `NA` for the `TRUE` element?

Tags: r

Why is the `TRUE` coerced to `NA` here

```
as.numeric(c(1, 1.0, "1.0", TRUE))
```

but not here:

```
as.numeric(c(1, 1.0, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is converting the `TRUE` to `"TRUE"` with the introduction of `"1.0"` - it is just the basic behavior of `vector` that it can have only a single `class` and there is precedence with `character` over `numeric`.  Thus, any character in the vector, converts the whole into  `character` class

```
c(1, 1.0, "1.0", TRUE)
[1] "1"    "1"    "1.0"  "TRUE"
```

This is also valid for other class conversions.

```
as.numeric(c(1, 1.0, "1.0", TRUE))
#[1]  1  1  1 NA
as.logical(c(1, 1.0, "1.0", TRUE))
[1]   NA   NA   NA TRUE
as.logical(c(1, 1.0,  TRUE))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In the third case, TRUE is coerced to 1 and except 0 all other values will be TRUE while in first case, numeric values are type converted, whereas "TRUE" is a string and it is not.  In the second case, we are converting to logical and thus `"TRUE"`, is converted to `TRUE` where as others are "characters" and thus returns NA

```
as.logical("1")
[1] NA
```